StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException Timeout
We are getting a lot of timeouts on a Azure redis cache on a Azure function in the same region with this error.
Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Request failed with PartStatusFunction
with json:
Exception Bibliotheca.Backend.Common.Caching.CacheTimeoutException: Cache has timed out when attempting operation ---> StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing GET (5000ms), next:
GET devicestate7fa34621-8e96-e911-2d94-0024e880a2b3, inst: 0, qu: 23, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: SpinningDown, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, last-in: 3680, cur-in: 416, sync-ops: 10578015, async-ops: 1, serverEndpoint: use-lcd-cache-prod-us.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, conn-sec: 70226.34, aoc: 0, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: WN0MDWK0000DS(SE.Redis-v2.6.122.38350), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=59,Free=32708,Min=4,Max=32767), v: 2.6.122.38350 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
The stats don't seem alarming.
I tried to run the SLOWLOG command in the redis console on the Azure, but it doesn't work.
Thanks
Anders

Specifically, Busy is greater than Min in "WORKER: (Busy=59,Free=32708,Min=4,Max=32767)" from the exception message. Thread pool minimums will need to be increased. Guidance is in the link supplied in the exception:
https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts
also Check out troubleshooting guide:
Troubleshoot Azure Cache for Redis latency and timeouts - Azure Cache for Redis | Microsoft Learn
. you will need to create a support case if you need more help.

I read it like it had 32708 Free and used 59, so thought it had a lort of free resources. I will try this thanks.
